# using this when including in php

Tags: this, php

in for example magento they have php seperated from phtml.

I also do the same thing.
But I can't figure one thing out, and that is:

When I have this php script:

```
class aclass extends main{
public function redirect(){
    require_once($this->frontend_folder . $this->admin_folder . "beheer/edit_account.phtml");
}

public function nav_menu(){
    return "<nav>some nav menu things in here</nav>";
}
```

and the "view" phtml script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="wrap">
        <?php
           echo $this->nav_menu();
        ?>
    </div>
</html>
```

"$this" doesn't work, but how can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to instantiate the class in the view.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="wrap">
        <?php
           $c = new aclass; // instantiate the class
           echo $c->nav_menu();  //  run the function from the class
           $c = null; //  null the variable, maybe help garbage collection...
        ?>
    </div>
</html>
```

this is not an optimal way to use it, but I hope the idea is clear.

EDIT:  This is a simple solution, depending on your archetecture, you can do many things.  In simpliest form, you should consider instantiating your class at the top of the view, then you can reference it by the handle you assign it to throughout the view.